# Does MySQL database optimize joins itself or do we have to specify the order to join?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query like the following

```
select f.number,SUM(ii.qty),SUM(c.g1),SUM(c.g2),SUM(c.g3),SUM(c.g4),SUM(c.g5),SUM(c.g6)  from 
farmer as f 
    inner join 
        issue as i on f.number = i.farmerno 
            inner join 
                item_issue as ii on i.recno = (ii.recno+0)
                    inner join 
                        crop as c on c.farmerno = f.number
where ii.item like 'S%' 
group by f.number
```

Do we have to think about the order of joins that would be optimal for the query or does MySQL figure out the best way of doing it?

Comment: Your order of joins is important.. If there is an index that mysql can use it'll generally be used.. But if you join a table and it filters rows it'll affect other joins

Comment: Also consider moving the where clause condition as part of join condition.  ii.item like 'S%'  and ii on i.recno = (ii.recno+0).

Answer (score 0):

You can view your query after the MySQL Optimizer had it by doing an

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...
```

This will give you a warning containing the query as it is really processed (what the optimizer had done with it). That way you can review the real join order.

As for performance you should make sure to use a B-TREE index on your `ii.item` column since you do a `LIKE` Operation. MySQL default are HASH indices which are not optimal for that.